# Multiple Dictionary in list Manipulation using Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Input string in the python : multiple dictionaries in the list

```
input = [{'a': '1', 'b':'2','c':'10'},{'a': '1', 'b':'3','c':'11'},{'a':'2','b':'19','c':'100']

output = [ {'1':{'b': ('2','3'),'c':('10','11')},'2':{'b':(19),'c':(100)}}]
```

Comment: Also, your output doesn't make sense. A dictionary can only have one value per key. That value can be a _list_ that contains multiple entities, but the list itself is still a single item. Your output shows _two_ dictionaries assigned to the `'1'` key.

Comment: Thanks Pranav, I have corrected the output string

Comment: @jay what will be the output for this input `[{'a': '1', 'd': 4, 'b':'2','c':'10'},{'a': '1', 'd': 4, 'b':'3','c':'11'}]` or `[{'a': '1', 'd': 4, 'b':'2','c':'10'},{'a': '1', 'b':'3', 'd': 4,'c':'11'}]`, maybe you want something like this: `[{'a': ('1')},{'b': ('2','3')},{'c':('10','11')}]`

Comment: @Chandan
input: [{'a': '1', 'd': 4, 'b':'2','c':'10'},{'a': '1', 'b':'3', 'd': 4,'c':'11'}]
output = [{'1':{'b':(2,3),'c':(10,11),'d':(4)}}]

Basically value of the key ('A') has to serve as key in the resultant output with all the other keys & their values in the array.

Hope it makes sense!!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the above solution but the issue is with the below use case: d = [{'a': '1', 'd': 4, 'b':'2','c':'10'},{'a': '1', 'd': 4, 'b':'3','c':'11'},{'a': '2', 'b':'3','c':'11'}] Current output: [{'2': {'b': ('2',), 'c': ('10',)}}] Expected Output: [{'1': {'b': ('2', '3'), 'c': ('10', '11')},'2': {'b': ('19'), 'c': ('100')}}]

Answer (score 0):

```py
def func(mylist):
    t = {}
    for i in d:
        itr = iter(i)
        k = i[next(itr)]
        tmp = t.get(k, {})
        for m in itr:
            n = i[m]
            if (tmp.get(m, None) == None):
                tmp[m] = tuple()
            if (i[m] not in set(tmp[m])):
                tmp[m] += (n,)
        t[k] = tmp
    print([t])

d = [{'a': '1', 'b':'2','c':'10'},{'a': '1', 'b':'3','c':'11'},{'a':'2','b':'19','c':'100'}]
func(d)
d = [{'a': '1', 'b':'2','c':'10'},{'a': '1', 'b':'3','c':'11'}]
func(d)
d = [{'a': '1', 'd': 4, 'b':'2','c':'10'},{'a': '1', 'd': 4, 'b':'3','c':'11'}]
func(d)
d = [{'a': '1', 'd': 4, 'b':'2','c':'10'},{'a': '1', 'b':'3', 'd': 4,'c':'11'}]
func(d)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the above solution but the issue is with the below use case:

d = [{'a': '1', 'd': 4, 'b':'2','c':'10'},{'a': '1', 'd': 4, 'b':'3','c':'11'},{'a': '2', 'b':'3','c':'11'}]

Current output:
[{'2': {'b': ('2',), 'c': ('10',)}}]

Expected Output:
[{'1': {'b': ('2', '3'), 'c': ('10', '11')},'2': {'b': ('19'), 'c': ('100')}}]

Comment: @jay i have updated the solution.

Answer (score 0):

def dic_to_output(dic,col):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
colname = list(df.columns)
#print(colname)
colname.remove(str(col))
df = df.groupby('a').agg(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index().set_index('a').T
return df.to_dict()
```

input = [{'a': '1', 'b':'2','c':'10'},{'a': '1', 'b':'3','c':'11'},{'a':'2','b':'19','c':'100'}]

dic_to_output(dic,'a')

output:
{'1': {'b': ['2', '3'], 'c': ['10', '11']}, '2': {'b': ['19'], 'c': ['100']}}